# Vuetify: why does my v-img allow dragging?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to prevent an image being dragged under certain circumstances:

```
  <template v-for="(cell,c) in row" :key="r*8 + c" >
    <v-img v-if=" !cell.used" class="canDragIt"
      :draggable="true"
      @dragstart="drag($event,idString(cell.id,r,c))"
      @drop="drop($event,r,c)"
      @dragover="allowDrop($event,r,c)"
      :src = cell.content
      width = "40"
      >
    </v-img>
    <v-img v-else class="cannotDrag"
      :src = cell.content
      width = "40"
      > 
    </v-img>
  </template>
```

I haven't added `:draggable="true"` to the `v-else` condition, but those elements still allow dragging ( I also tried adding `:draggable="false"` without success). I know that the `v-if` condtion is working correctly because the class changes as planned.
Other elements in my design (e.g. some `v-chip`s ) don't alow dragging unless I set `draggable` to be true

I have found a workaround by adding

```
@dragstart="stopDrag($event)"
```

and then `preventDefault()` in the event handler, but this shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always drag images in the browser. Try the same with a `<div>`.
It works well.

I have changed your code to switch `dragable` for one `div`.

```
<v-switch label="Allow Drag&Drop" v-model="allow" style="margin: 20px;"></v-switch>
       <div v-for="(cell,c) in row" :key="c" >
         <div class="canDragIt"
               :draggable="allow" >
           <div :style="{ 'background-color': (allow ? 'green' : 'red'), 'width': '200px', height: '100px', margin: '10px', padding: '40px' }">   
            <center>{{ !allow ? 'No' : ''}} Drag & Drop</center>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the working [Vuetify Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: I marked your answer as correct but then realised that what you are doing is setting `:draggable=false` which is what I tried , but it didn't stop dragging. So what else have I missed?

Comment: As I said, you can always drag an image. And it looks like you can still drag selected text. Which I guess it's a basic browser functionality, and I am not sure if it can be suppressed.

Comment: Pay attention how the whole colored `<div>` could be dragged or not dependent on the switch position.